# How can I compute the area of overlap of 2 histograms?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to get the area of overlap of 2 histograms.

I was able to extract the histogram data of my 2 datasets (from similar columns of 2 dataframes). I also used `density = True` so that the area under the curve would be 1.

```
hist_data1, bin_edges1 = np.histogram(data1.iloc[:, 1], bins = 50, density = True)
hist_data2, bin_edges2 = np.histogram(data2.iloc[:, 1], bins = 50, density = True)
```

I am trying to follow the method used [here](https://blog.datadive.net/histogram-intersection-for-change-detection/):

```
def histogram_intersection(h1, h2, bins):
    bins = numpy.diff(bins)
    sm = 0
    for i in range(len(bins)):
        sm += min(bins[i]*h1[i], bins[i]*h2[i])
    return sm
```

However, `bin_edges1` may not be the exactly the same as in `bin_edges2` so there is no uniform `bins` that can be used in `histogram_intersection()`. How can I use the above method such that the `bins` would be uniform?

Comment: please include a minimum reproducable sample in your code. Right now, you are lacking sample data.

Comment: You need a common minimum `bmin = np.minimum(data1.iloc[:, 1].min(), data2.iloc[:, 1].min(),)` and maximum (`bmax = ....`). And then create your own `bin_edges = np.linspace(bmin, bmax, 51)`. These go as input to both calls to `np.histogram(..., bins=bin_edges)`,

Comment: If you include sample data I can take a look

Comment: I tried setting the `bins` for the second dataset to `bins = bin_edges1`, and it worked. I suppose this method is similar to the one suggested by JohanC. What do you think?

Comment: @tgwsk That carries the downside that if the range of data2 exceeds the range of data1, then some data will land outside of any bins and not be counted. Might be okay, depending on your application, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for the insight. I checked and in my case, the range of data1 exceeds the range of data2.